# Finding Mouse click position in IconView in GTK

Tags: application-development, python, gtk

I am building a file browser using `Gtk.IconView` in python. I am trying to find the path of an icon selected using " selection-changed" signal using `gtk.IconView.get_path_at_pos(x,y)`.

The docs are mum on how to obtain the `(x,y)`. How do I find them?

Comment: Close voters: This is not off-topic, questions about development on Ubuntu are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

To get the path, you should be able to do something like this (untested):

```
    def on_iconview_selection_changed(self, widget):
        try:
            path = widget.get_selected_items()[0]
        except IndexError:
            # No icon selected, so the list returned by get_selected_items() is
            # empty and indexing returns an IndexError
            path = None
```